# How can I get the modified value of an input field within the onPaste event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, onpaste

I'm handling the `onPaste` event in a React application. The problem I'm having is that the `value` of the element isn't updated until after the paste event has finished and thus I'm unable to determine whether the pasted data *overwrites* the existing value or *extends* upon the existing value.

In the following snippet, if you have the word "cheese" copied into your clipboard and freshly run the snippet for both of the below scenarios:

1. Paste the word *at the end* of the existing value, so that it becomes "123cheese".
2. Paste the word *over* the existing value, so that it becomes "cheese".

In both, the logged `value` will be equal to "123" and it's not possible to determine how the value has changed with the `value` property alone.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  handlePaste(e) {
    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData.getData('text');
    const value = e.target.value;
    
    console.log("Pasted:", clipboardData);
    console.log("Value:", value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <input defaultValue="123" onPaste={this.handlePaste.bind(this)} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
<p>tl;dr: Please refer to the instructions above the snippet.</p>
```

Now I'm well aware that a potential solution would be to delay the code I'm wanting to execute within the handler until after the event has finished, but this feels hacky and unnecessary:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  handlePaste(e) {
    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData.getData('text');
    ((target) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const value = target.value;
    
        console.log("Pasted:", clipboardData);
        console.log("Value:", value);
      }, 100)
    })(e.target);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <input defaultValue="123" onPaste={this.handlePaste.bind(this)} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

How can I get the modified value (or what the value will become) within an `onPaste` event handler?